# Difference between two uses of conditional

Tags: grammaire, conditionnel, conditions

Do the following two sentences have the same meaning?

> J'aurais tourné à droite, on serait arrivé plus rapidement.
>
> Si j'avais tourné à droite, on serait arrivé plus rapidement.

If not, why and which is preferred?

Answer (score 1):

La première forme, que j'aurais plutôt écrite :

*- J'aurais tourné à droite **que l'on** serait arrivé plus rapidement. (que l'on ou qu'on)*

utilise dans sa principale un conditionnel passé. (auxiliaire au conditionnel présent + participe passé)

L'usage du conditionnel passé laisse évidemment passer une idée d'hypothèse mais, en plus, **une nuance de regret**.
C'est cette nuance de regret propre au conditionnel passé qui fait la différence avec ta seconde phrase. Pas d'expression implicite de regret dans la seconde.

La phrase à préférer dépend donc du contexte.

- 1/ Si tu regrettes sans exprimer ce regret explicitement,
- 2/ Si tu ne regrettes pas ( la phrase se continue par... *mais je ne t'aurais jamais rencontré* ) ou si le regret est explicite... ***@&!!@## de @&@@!$ de !!&#!@***, si j'avais tourné...

Pour l'exemple hein!

**EDIT** Pour justifier ma réécriture de la proposition 1 et commenter l'observation de jlliagre dans l'OP :

On remarque que, dans chacune des deux tournures proposées par l'OP, il est deux propositions. L'une portant la condition et l'autre portant son effet.

- Dans la seconde : *on serait arrivé plus rapidement* est la proposition principale, *j'avais tourné à droite* la proposition subordonnée introduite par la conjonction *si*.
  C'est la présence de *si* qui donne l'information de subordination. (on peut d'ailleurs inverser les deux propositions sans perdre ni en sens ni en correction.) L'information de subordination est donnée par la syntaxe.
- La première phrase telle que proposée par l'OP est tout à fait correcte. (d'où mon ***je*** l'aurais plutôt écrite). Mais à la différence de la seconde ne porte pas d'information de subordination entre les deux propositions. On ne peut pas non plus déduire la subordination d'une concordance de temps puisque les temps et modes sont identiques dans les deux propositions. 
  C'est cette conjonction *que*, que je préfère pour ma part ajouter, qui va la donner.

**SUPEREDIT** pour l'histoire d'une seconde raison au *que* : (déconseillé aux âmes sensibles)

Le conditionnel n'existe pas en latin. C'est le subjonctif qui permettait d'exprimer les faits irréels, la possibilité.
La langue littéraire lui a emboîté le pas et, de façon littéraire, on dirait bien plutôt : ... (C'est bon ? vous êtes bien assis ?) ... GO! :

*J'**eusse tourné** à droite **que** l'on **fût arrivé** plus rapidement*

Brrrr Deux subjonctifs, plus que parfait en plus... excusez du peu! ça va en glacer certains ici... non ?
Mais bon... ça marche très bien et c'est bien ainsi que... on... **eût dit** (héhé!)... comme il faut.

Deux propositions ? deux temps et modes identiques ? laquelle porte la condition ? laquelle l'effet ? => conjonction obligatoire.

Je crois pouvoir dire que c'est cette forme qui s'est imprimée dans nos oreilles, on a changé les modes et les temps pour simplifier (et heureusement!!) mais on a gardé la syntaxe, c'est à dire cette nécessité de la conjonction.

Bref! Quoi qu'il en soit, deux temps modes identiques dans les deux propositions, il faudra laisser le lecteur attendre le point final pour ne pas croire qu'il s'agit d'une succession de conditions.
*J'aurais tourné à droite, je serais arrivé plus rapidement, je ne me serais pas fait arrêter par la police,...* à chaque virgule, le lecteur va se poser la question. Une conjonction lui permet de trancher immédiatement.
Donc... Oui l'écriture initiale de l'OP est correcte... ma formulation est plus cool vis à vis du lecteur. **Ce n'est donc pas une question d'oreille.**

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence is what everyone uses:

> *Si j'avais tourné à droite, on serait arrivé plus rapidement.*

While we would understand the intended meaning, the first sentence:

> *J'aurais tourné à droite, on serait arrivé plus rapidement.*

is not very idiomatic, if at all. Most native French speakers would avoid using it in the first place. Deciding whether it is grammatically correct or dubious is moot. An idiomatic sentence with the same starting words might have been:

> *J'aurais tourné à droite si j'avais vu le panneau à temps.*

Note that

> ***Si*** j'aurais tourné à droite...

is quickly identified as very incorrect by native French.

Comment: very incorrect, but very much in use, especially to make fun of the fact that it's incorrect

Comment: @GeorgeM Not sure if it is that much used outside quoting *Le petit Gibus* famous "*Si j'aurais su, j'aurais pas venu*" in *La guerre des boutons*.

Comment: Maybe this is a regional thing, or maybe it's just me, but the first sentence is to my opinion very idiomatic in Belgium. A quite common expression is "Tu aurais voulu le faire exprès que tu n'aurais pas sû".

Comment: @LaurentS. It might be you ... or it might be me. The grammar is correct but I don't remember having heard that form a lot compared to the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Les deux phrases dans la question sont entièrement correctes et équivalentes et il n'y a pas de difficulté de compréhension en raison d'une conjonction manquante. On peut remplacer en préservant l'équivalene « J'aurais tourné à droite » par « Si j'avais tourné à droite »; on identifie cela sans ambigüité.

«J'aurais tourné à droit, on serait arrivé plus rapidement. » n'est pas équivalent à «J'aurais tourné à droite, qu'on serait arrivé plus rapidement. » . Cette dernière tournure semble gauche, parait ne pas être utilisé. Le conditionnel avec « **que...ne...pas** » sert à exprimer qu'une action A, jugée ne pas servir le but d'une action C et donc évitée à la faveur d'une autre (B) sans ce défaut, se révèle après le test de l'action C, n'être pas moins apte à servir le but proposé (C); ex: Il auraient été mieux payés, qu'ils n'en auraient pas été plus vaillants pour ça. «J'aurais tourné à droite, qu'on ne serait pas arrivé plus lentement. »